# How to verify that every object responsible for Itself

Tags: design, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, domain-driven-design, class-design

I wonder if I have multiple objects and how to list their responsibilities where

> every Object Must be Responsible for Itself

for example: If I have three objects:

```
Employee,Schedule,Shift.
```

and the `setShift()`, `createShedule()`,....etc

---

Where should these behaviors belong to ? in the `Employee` or in the objects which affected by these actions!!

It's very confusing because I ended up that most of the methods belong to one object in my case `Employee`! It turns to like a god/master object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explanation on how "Tell, Don't Ask" is considered good OO](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/157526/explanation-on-how-tell-dont-ask-is-considered-good-oo)

Comment: You need to better explain what you mean by "responsible for itself". Right now, it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: with regards to avoiding god object, see also [How to determine if a class meets the single responsibility principle?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/154723/31260)

Comment: @Euphoric I mean where should I put the responsibilities in the `employee` who does the action or for example `shift` which affected by the action

Comment: It seems all you have done so far is define the domain objects. You still need something that typically sits outside that to tell the objects what to do - possibly using some kind of design pattern. Hard to advise further without a bit more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you missed a domain object. The scheduler.

```
dayShift.setShift("7am","3pm");
shifts.add(dayShift);
Schedule schedule = evenHoursScheduler.createSchedule(shifts, employees);
```

Not every domain object is an object you can point to in the real world. Sometimes it's a role to be played.